# Is there a way to insert data directly from kafka to a table in ignite data base without using ignite cache?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite

I have tried loading data from kafka topic to ignite cache using IgniteSinkConnector  then using some java application I am loading data from cache to database table but this is bit slow can any one tell is there any way to load data directly from topic to table.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no distinction between a cache and a table in Ignite. You can insert into a cache using IgniteSinkConnector and run SQL queries against the same data.